# replaceWith in a variable

Tags: jquery

I have an input field where users are allowed to enter text, including `<a href>` links. What I would like to do is then to use this value both rendered as html and as plain text with only the contents of each `<a href>` tag displayed.

I figured out that I can use the snippet below to replace the `<a href>` tags by their contents.

```
$("a").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); }).val();
```

Example html:

```
input: <input type="text" id="input"/><br />
plain output: <div id="outputplain"></div><br />
replaced output: <div id="outputreplaced"></div><br />
```

Example JS:

```
// simulate user input
$('#input').val('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">me</a> and <a href="http://stackexchange.com">you</a>');

// try to render
$('#input').click(function() {
    var input = $(this).val();

    // html rendered
    $('#outputplain').html(input);

    // plain rendered
    $('#outputreplaced').html(input);
    $("#outputreplaced a").replaceWith(function() { return $(this).contents(); });
});
```

The above example works but what I would really like to do is keep outputplain and outputreplaced as variables so that I can send them to a template later on. I can however not figure out how to do the replacement without outputting to the page.

I'm not limited to using replaceWith, any solution which allows me to strip the tags from the variable is welcome.

Comment: use $('a').attr('href',LINKHERE);

Comment: You want to get #input value after replaceWith?

Comment: Yes the replaceWith is only supposed to change the loaded value, not the actual value of the input (which the user might want to tweak further)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a temp jQuery object(dom) like

```js
// simulate user input
$('#input').val('<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">me</a> and <a href="http://stackexchange.com">you</a>');

// try to render
$('#input').click(function() {
  var input = $(this).val();

  // html rendered
  $('#outputplain').text(input);

  var $tmp = $('<div />', {
    html: input
  });
  $tmp.find('a').contents().unwrap();

  var replaced = $tmp.html();
  // plain rendered
  $('#outputreplaced').text(replaced);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="input" />
<div id="outputplain"></div>
<div id="outputreplaced"></div>
```

Also, as you can see there is a method called [.unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) which helps you to take a element out of its parent

Comment: There is a missing semicolon at the end of the $tmp definition (which stackoverflow won't let me fix). Otherwise this works perfectly. Many thanks!